# Issue with running a single prediction with PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, torch

I have a trained model using PyTorch now I want to simpy run it on one example

```
>>> model
nn.Sequential {
  [input -> (0) -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> (5) -> (6) -> (7) -> (8) -> (9) -> (10) -> output]
  (0): nn.SpatialConvolutionMap
  (1): nn.Tanh
  (2): nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2x2, 2, 2)
  (3): nn.SpatialConvolutionMap
  (4): nn.Tanh
  (5): nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2x2, 2, 2)
  (6): nn.Reshape(6400)
  (7): nn.Linear(6400 -> 128)
  (8): nn.Tanh
  (9): nn.Linear(128 -> 5)
  (10): nn.LogSoftMax
}
```

Then I load an image from my test set:

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
transformation = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]) 
image_tensor = transformation(image).float()
inp = Variable(image_tensor)
```

and finally try to run the network

```
output = model(inp)
```

But I get error **TypeError: 'Sequential' object is not callable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your model is not [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Sequential) (**py**torch `Sequential`), but rather [`torch.legacy.nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/legacy.html) (a legacy lua torch model).
Try using this model `forward()` explicitly:

```
output = model.forward(inp[None, ...])  # don't forget to add "batch" dimension
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be it, but now I get error: oubleSpatialConvolutionMap_updateOutput received an invalid combination of arguments - got (int, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, Tensor, int, int, int, int), but expected (int state, torch.DoubleTensor input, torch.DoubleTensor output, torch.DoubleTensor weight, torch.DoubleTensor bias, torch.DoubleTensor connTable, int nInputPlane, int nOutputPlane, int dW, int dH)

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan try converting your legacy model into a pytorch model. it would be easier to work that way.